# Separating sub navigation and top level navigation configuration in my module.config.php

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

Using zf2 I have a subnav bar that appears on every page of one of my modules. Its rendered with a view helper and a partial (all contained in the module). The module pulls the config from its own module.config.php:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'aaa',
            'route' => 'aaa',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'bbb',
            'route' => 'bbb',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'ccc',
            'route' => 'ccc', ...
```

Now I want to add a configuration for my site wide navbar that is rendered in the application module. The problem of course is that the configs are merged so I can't just add a 'navigation' key in the application module's module.config.php.

What's the best when to handle this? How can I have my module specific subnavs and my top level nav stored and segregated in the service manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem of course is that the configs are merged

Why is that a problem?

Application (module.config.php)

```
'navigation' => array(
   'default' => array(
     // application pages...
   )
 ),
```

FooModule (module.config)

```
'navigation' = array(
  'foo_nav' => array(
     // foo pages...
   ),
   'foo_module_specific_sidebar_name' = array(
     // foo sidebar pages
   )
),
```

Merged config

```
'navigation' => array(
   'default' => array(
     // application pages...
   ),
  'foo_nav' => array(
     // foo pages...
   ),
   'foo_module_specific_sidebar_name' = array(
     // foo sidebar pages
   )
),
```

ZF2 merges using [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array too

Providing you you are not duplicating the navigation names and have [the appropriate factories](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/Service/DefaultNavigationFactory.php) *where* you place the config doesn't really matter.

Comment: How to I access the other configs? Right now call my view helper in the views like this $this->navbar('navigation'). How would I pass a nested array inside of the navigation config?